# Retain form values on save

Tags: extjs

I have a basic form with URL and Title fields. I want to retain the form values when the form is closed so on reopening of form the saved values gets updated to the fields. I know I can store these values in database and retrieve them, but is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Do you know how to use a viewModel? We usually bind the fields to a viewModel formData at a higher point in hirachy. That way on reopening you still have the values and you decide, when to delete the items.

Comment: check out local storage - [Ext JS Local storage](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage.html)

Comment: As @Dinkheller, mentioned you can use a viewModel to bind data to. frm.getValues() to get the form values. But it also depends the toolkit, classic or modern; and what event you will be storing the updated form values on. Please provide more details on the question you are asking.